# Boundedness and closedness of the set

Tags: functional-analysis

> Prove or disprove the boundedness and closedness of the set $S=\left\{f\in L_2[0,1]:\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1\dfrac{|f(x)|}{x}dx\leq1\right\}$.

It’s impossible to me here to prove/disprove even the boundedness. Please, give me any idea for this. All i know about this set -- it is not precompact.

Comment: I can't prove that $\int\limits_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\leq c$. I don't see the way to connect this condition with what is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Closedness:** let $(f_n) \subset S$ be a sequence converging in $L^2$ to $f \in L^2([0,1])$. Then, up to extracting a subsequence, we may assume that $f_n \to f$ a.e. Now, by Fatou's lemma, we have
$$\int_0^1 \frac{|f(x)|}{x} \, dx \leqslant \liminf_n\int_0^1 \frac{|f_n(x)|}{x}\, dx \leqslant 1.$$
Thus $S$ is closed.

**Boundedness:** $S$ is not bounded. For example, take $f_n(x) = Cn\mathbf{1}_{(1-1/n,1]}(x)$ for some constant $C>0$. Then
$$\int_0^1 \frac{|f_n(x)|}{x}\, dx = Cn\int_{1-1/n}^1\frac{dx}{x}= -Cn\log(1-1/n).$$
Since $-n\log(1-1/n) \to 1$, we may choose $C>0$ such that $-Cn\log(1-1/n) \leqslant 1$ for every $n$. For this choice of $C$, $f_n \in S$. However, 
$$\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2\, dx = C^2n^2 \int_{1-1/n}^{1}dx=C^2n, $$
and $(f_n)$ is not bounded in $L^2$.